# Terms definition in Balance of Payment

Tags: macroeconomics, international-trade, international-economics, open-economy-macro, balance-of-payments

I have problems in distinguishing among terms in the Balance of Payment / the international balance sheet of a nation.

As far as I know, on Assets and Liabilities sides of BPM, there are **Portfolio Equity, Portfolio Debt, FDI, Other Debts.**

What is the difference between Portfolio Equity and Portfolio Debt? Is it true that Portfolio Equity is about stocks/shares, whereas Portfolio Debt is about Bonds?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement *"Portfolio Equity is about stocks/shares, whereas Portfolio Debt is about bonds"* is essentially correct, with the associated income being dividends and coupons respectively

Direct investment (FDI) has the associated income of profits, while other debts may have the associated income of interest (if any)

[Chapter 6](https://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/bop/2007/pdf/chap6.pdf) and other chapters of the [IMF Balance of Payments Manual](https://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/bop/2007/bopman6.htm) discuss these issues